# Track if class is in viewport

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fire off a trigger when a user has a class in the viewport. Ideally this would be for each section heading;

```
<h2 class="section-heading">About</h2>
```

If the class falls into the viewport I would like to fire off a virtual page view along the lines of;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   dataLayer.push({
      'event':'VirtualPageview',
      'virtualPageURL':{{Page Hostname}},
      'virtualPageTitle':{{Page URL}}
});
</script>
```

If anyone knows how I could set this up I would be very grateful. It is for a one-page site.

Comment: This plugin is designed to do exactly that, check if things are in the viewport. https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport You'll have to figure out when to fire the check; A common pattern is to check on both scroll and page resize.

Answer (score 1):

**Update!**

Use the new [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It's supported by all modern browsers except Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver

Here's a polyfill for IE and Safari: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/gh-pages/polyfill

**Old answer:**

I use the [waypoints plugin](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) in a couple of projects and it works great.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('section-heading'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    alert('You have scrolled to a thing')
  }
})
```

Here's the full doc: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is definitely your best shot at doing this.

It's supported by most browsers and has a [polyfill](https://github.com/jeremenichelli/intersection-observer-polyfill) for the few that don't support it yet.

[This post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) on the google developers blog should be definitely helpful in showing you its basic use, which could be roughly something like this:

```
var io = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        //Do something with the entries, e.g. push to the dataLayer
        console.log(entries);
    }
); 

io.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('section-heading'));
```

This way you're registering the observer to execute the callback whenever a `.section-heading` enters the viewport, which should be what you're willing to accomplish.